# Understanding the relation between MTCE & MTCO2E

Tags: recycling, carbon-footprint, usa

How do I convert MTCE/ton to MTCO2E/metric ton? Should I multiply it by 1.1 (ton to metric ton) and then by 3.67 (MTCE to MTCO2E)? For example, take a look at Exhibit ES5 [here](https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPDF.cgi/60000AVO.PDF?Dockey=60000AVO.PDF). Recycling aluminum cans, it says, saves 3.71 MTCE/ton. Is it 15 in MTCO2E/metric ton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To convert from MTCE to MTCO<sub>2</sub>E, divide by 12/44

The difference between MTCE and MTCO<sub>2</sub>E is a function of the number of carbon atoms in each molecule of the greenhouse gases included in the inventory. There's a note on page five of [the report](https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPDF.cgi/60000AVO.PDF?Dockey=60000AVO.PDF) that explains this (emphasis added):

> In this report, emissions of CO<sub>2</sub>, CH<sub>4</sub>, N<sub>2</sub>O, and PFCs have been converted to their “carbon equivalents.” **Because CO<sub>2</sub> is 12/44 carbon by weight, 1 metric ton of CO<sub>2</sub> is equal to 12/44 or 0.27 metric tons of carbon equivalent (MTCE)**. The MTCE value for 1 metric ton of each of the other gases is determined by multiplying its GWP by a factor of 12/44. (All data provided here are from the IPCC, Climate Change 1995: The Science of Climate Change, 1996, p. 121.)

#### To convert from short ton to metric ton, multiply by 1000/907.18474

Per Wikipedia, a [short ton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_ton) is equivalent to 907.18474 kg.